# Reload ng-repeat, with new data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, reload

I have a service, where I just return a list with all the available videos, which is then injected in a controller, so I can do a `ng-repeat` to list those videos. Just like so

```
videosApp.factory('VideosService', function ($http, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.videos = {
        list: [],
    };

    $http.get('/panel/videos')
        .then(
            function (response) {
                $rootScope.videos.list = response.data;
            },
            function () {
                alert('what is the velocity of a swallow?');
            }
        );

    return $rootScope;
});

videosApp.controller('VideosController', [
    '$scope', '$http', '$filter', '$window',
    function ($scope, $http, VideosService) {

        $scope.deleteVideo = function(id) {    
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this video?')) {
                $http.delete('/panel/videos/'+id)
                    .then(
                        function (response) {
                            growl(response.data.message, 'success');
                        },
                        function (response) {
                            growl(response.data.message, 'danger');
                        }
                    );
            }
        }

    }
]);
```

And now, for the HTML output:

```
<div id="videos-listing" class="row" ng-controller="VideosController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="video in videos.list">
            {{video.name}}
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a role="menuitem" href="#delete" ng-click="deleteVideo(video.id)">Delete</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now, as you can see, there is a `Delete` function also, which works perfectly. My issue, stands on how to refresh that listing, after a specific item has been deleted.

I cab wrap the `get /panel/videos` in a function and call it again after the delete is successful, but then, how do I refresh that ng-repeat? Or, is there any better way of doing it?

Comment: Have u tried calling /panel/videos after deleting, that should automatically refresh the view!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

**HTML**

```
<a role="menuitem" href="#delete" ng-click="deleteVideo(video)">Delete</a>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.deleteVideo = function(video) {    
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this video?')) {
        $http.delete('/panel/videos/'+video.id)
            .then(
                function (response) {
                    growl(response.data.message, 'success');
                    $scope.videos.list.splice($scope.videos.list.indexOf(video),1);
                },
                function (response) {
                    growl(response.data.message, 'danger');
                }
            );
    }
}
```

**Update**

Also, you can consider using some Collection helpers, like [Backbone's Collections](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection)

Your code would look like that, then:

JS:

```
$rootScope.videos.list = new Backbone.Collection();
$rootScope.videos.list.reset(response.data);

...
$scope.videos.list.remove(video);
```

HTML

```
<li ng-repeat="video in videos.list.models">
```

It also adds many other nice features to have ;)

Comment: Much better, then doing another server request. Great suggestion.

Comment: Or you could use **[Lodash](http://lodash.com/docs#remove)** `_.remove($scope.videos.list, video);`